# Sql Server Agent Error for SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, dts

Running a job as the SQL Server Agent Service Account Proxy account and the following error is haunting me . I cant get round it . Any ideas ?

Executed as user: EMEA\USERx$. Microsoft (R)

SQL Server Execute Package Utility

Version 10.0.1600.22 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.

Started:  16:53:26  Error: 2012-01-04 16:53:59.60

Code: 0xC0029151

Source: Task 1 - Importing Excel Files To Local Disk From Sharepoint

Site     Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "C:\Template\Import.bat" "" at "",

The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

```
Started:  16:53:26  Finished: 16:53:59  Elapsed:  33.478 seconds.
```

The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Answer (score 1):

If it runs when you run it manually, I would check permissions on the file location first to ensure the agent has permissions. I would also check the directory exists on the machine it is running on.

Comment: Might also verify the `C:\Template\Import.bat` file exists and works as expected